# Set large value to div's height

Tags: javascript, html, browser, scroll, scrollbar

I have a problem with height limitation of `<div></div>` in some web browsers, like Firefox. I have javascript code like this:

```
$('#MyDiv').css("height","20000000px"); // 20,000,000 pixel height
```

But I see `height: 2e+7px;` rule in the firebug. This problem exist in IE too, But in google chrome everything is ok and I see `height: 20000000px;`. How can I set very large value to div's height in a way that works for most browsers?

**EDIT:** firefox has no scrollbar in this div, but google chrome has scrollbar.

Comment: 20 millions? What that would be for?

Comment: I use jqGrid plugin and I need to show 1,000,000 records in it. This plugin have a div inside its container and that div has "height" css property. each record has 23px height and as a result total height of div will equal 23,000,000 pixels. But firefox doesn't recognize this value.

Comment: And does it really render 1 million records in reasonable time?

Comment: Yes. I use virtual scrolling and the grid just render visible part of data. My problem is not related to jqGrid, it is browser limitation problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I want just confirm the problem which describes **hamed**. One can try the demo http://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/y4tLxx53/4/ which contains setting `height` property using `jQuery.css` on the test div:

```js
var testValues = [10000, 1533916, 1533917, 1533918, 10737418, 10737419,
                  17895696, 17895697, 17895698, 20000000], h, i;
for (i = 0; i < testValues.length; i++) {
    h = testValues[i] + "px";
    $("#test").css("height", h);
    $("#log").append("<span>After setting height " +  h +
                     ", one have height: " + $("#test").css("height") +
                     "</span><br/>");
}
```

with very simple HTML markup

```js
<div id="log"></div>
<div id="test"></div>
```

One can see in Google Chrome the expected results

[image]

but Firefox shows

[image]

and IE10 and IE11 displays

[image]

instead.

By the way, the setting of large `height` on divs will be used to implement "virtual scrolling" (for example in [jqGrid](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=6)). So that the user sees div with large scroll and a table inside. If the user uses scroll bar then the page of data will be downloaded from the server via Ajax. In the way the `height` of the div should corresponds to the size of data on the server. If one row of table data have height 23px, then IE10/IE11 can simulate in the simple way only 66692 rows of virtual data in IE (1533916/23=66692) and 778073 rows (less as a million rows) in Firefox. The demos shows that one need use more sophisticated implementation of "virtual scrolling" to have no, described above, problems with setting of `height` of div.

One can use the same inline demo alternatively:

```js
var testValues = [10000, 1533916, 1533917, 1533918, 10737418, 10737419,
                  17895696, 17895697, 17895698, 20000000], h, i;
for (i = 0; i < testValues.length; i++) {
    h = testValues[i] + "px";
    $("#test").css("height", h);
    $("#log").append("<span>After setting height " +  h +
                     ", one have height: " + $("#test").css("height") +
                     "</span><br/>");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="log"></div>
<div id="test"></div>
```

Comment: More information is available at https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1205604

Answer (score 2):

I have run into the same issue implementing virtual scrolling. My solution is to detect numbers that are too large and use a multiplier.

This means that the height of the overflowed content will be `realHeight / multiplier`. And when I'm trying to figure out what data to show, I just take the `scrollTop * multiplier`. This works fine to the user because the scrollbar has a minimum height.

This will work if you have control over the effect. I'm not familiar with jqGrid, but the source code may have to be updated.

Comment: Assuming you have a `multiplier` of 2, doesn't that make scrolling with the mouse wheel twice as fast as normal? Doesn't this confuse the user?

Answer (score 1):

That's not a problem. The value `2e+7` is the same as `20000000`, it's just a different way of showing the number.

In some tools, large numbers are shown in [scientific notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation). The number `2e+7` means 2 * 10<sup>7</sup>.

Comment: Yes, you're right. But scroll bar is missing in this notation. Please read my updated answer. Thanks.

Comment: @hamed: That's a different matter. The style is set correctly, but the browser isn't designed to handle an element that large. The largest height that I can make work for a div in Firefox is 17895697 pixels. The maximum in IE is 10737418 pixels.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Is there any way to solve this problem in firefox? In fact, I need to have scrollbar in firefox like google chrome on very large divs.

Comment: No, you can't overcome the limitations of the browsers. All browsers have some limitations like that. Chome also have a limitation on the size of elements, even if it is a lot higher (1.797693e+308). If you need to support a little older browsers you might have to keep the elements even smaller. I would expect for example IE 7 to have an even lower limit.

Comment: @Guffa: I posted [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28414821/315935) with the demo which demonstrates the problem in IE10/IE11 and Firefox. I answered some previous question of **hamed**, so I described shortly where are from the problem.

Answer (score -1):

If your document is size is not fixed, you can use this:

```
var height = $(document).height();
```

and set your div container height accordingly

```
$('#MyDiv').css("height",height);
```

This should work on all the browsers