# free-jqgrid tool bar buttons wrapping in a second row

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, free-jqgrid

When adding add, edit, delete and other buttons to a free-jgGrid tool bar using a pager, they wrap to a second row at nearly 50% of the grid width.

I'm not using pagination, but I do use record count (grid properties *scroll: 1, viewrecords: true*).

In the example I set on jsFiddle, you can see that Delete and Refresh buttons wrap on a second row, although there is plenty space to set them in the first one.

This behavior isn't observed in jgGrid.

I wonder if it is possible to have all buttons in a single row, being the grid width large enough ?

JSFiddle code snippet ( forked from an [OlegKi's example](https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/e6hu02z4/)): [JSFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/bft286tz/2/)

```js
$(function () {
    "use strict";
    $("#grid").jqGrid({
        colModel: [
            { name: "firstName", width: 200 },
            { name: "lastName", width: 200 }
        ],
        data: [
            { id: 10, firstName: "Angela", lastName: "Merkel" },
            { id: 20, firstName: "Vladimir", lastName: "Putin" },
            { id: 30, firstName: "David", lastName: "Cameron" },
            { id: 40, firstName: "Barack", lastName: "Obama" },
            { id: 50, firstName: "François", lastName: "Hollande" }
        ],
        pager: "#pager",
        viewrecords: true,
        gridview: true,
        scroll: 1,
    })
.jqGrid('navGrid',
      '#pager',
      {edit: true, edittext: 'Edit',
       add: true, addtext: 'Add',
       del: true, deltext: 'Del',
       search:false,
       view: true, viewtext: 'View',
       refresh: true, refreshtext: 'Refresh'}       
      );
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/free-jqgrid/4.15.4/css/ui.jqgrid.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/free-jqgrid/4.15.4/jquery.jqgrid.min.js"></script>

<table id="grid"></table>
<div id="pager"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I correctly understand, what you need, then the option `pagerRightWidth` with small enough value (see [the documentation](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/blob/v4.15.4/ts/free-jqgrid.d.ts#L1244)), will be what you need.

Additionally the usage of `scroll: 1` isn't recommended. The option `gridview: true` is enabled by default in free jqGrid and it can be removed. In your case you can use `pgbuttons: false, pginput: false` options to remove paging buttons. See https://jsfiddle.net/bft286tz/8/, which uses the following options

```js
    ...
    pager: true,
    pgbuttons: false,
    pginput: false,
    viewrecords: true,
    pagerRightWidth: 90
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. It worked fine. I have the following questions: Your link points to the point where pagerRightWidth is defined in code. Where is it documented ? Another question is why scroll: 1 isn't recommended ?

Comment: @RomualdoCaruso: [free-jqgrid.d.ts](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/blob/v4.15.4/ts/free-jqgrid.d.ts) **defines** only the interfaces, properties, callback functions and events, which are implemented currently. It's defined in TypeScript, but it's not really *code*. In any way it describes the options inclusive *type* and possible values of options. The answer on "why" question could be very long because of many details. Short to say: the implementation of "scroll: 1" is bad. I don't remove the feature from the code, but I don't recommend you to use it. Use local paging instead.

Comment: I did accepted the answer ( clicking on the up arrow: This answer was useful ), but as I have a less than 15 score points, it says that the public answer score isn't displayed. Or is there another way to accept the answer ( I'm not very familiar with Stackoverflow, excluseme ). Thanks again.

Comment: On the other hand, I use scroll = 1, because I need infinite scrolling. Should I create a new question on Stack Overflow to continue discussing this issue ?

Comment: @RomualdoCaruso: The explanation of the reasons why the usage of virtual scrolling (`scroll: 1`) is bad could be long and oriented on the knowledge on implementation details. Short to say it works only in case of many hard restrictions, which makes the usage if the features unneeded. If you examine limitations part of jqGrid features (grouping, frozen columns, ...) you will see that the features not work with virtual scrolling. If not all lines of grid have the same height, virtual scrolling will work wrong. If you loads data via Ajax request if could work wrong depend on response time...

Comment: @RomualdoCaruso: If the total number of rows large, then virtual scrolling works wrong. The limit depend on web browsers. For IE11 it's about 66692 rows (see [here](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/bugs/virtual-scrolling-in-ie-cand-display-more-as-about-66700-rows), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28414821/315935) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28255394/315935))... I don't found any easy way to fix existing problems without rewriting large parts of jqGrid code and probably changing some internals structures, which breaks upwards compatibility.

Comment: Ok @Oleg: That said I will only beg you not to remove the feature, as many customers of mine are very used to it. Thanks.